# Лента новостей (пользователь не хочет что бы его записи показывало)

Tags: sql

Подскажите как реализовать sql запрос в ленте новостей, если допустим один из моих друзей не хочет что бы его записи отображались в ленте новостей сейчас работает вот так:

```
SELECT * FROM lenta WHERE 
user IN (SELECT user FROM frends WHERE frend = '$myid')
```

в таблице с юзерами `users` сделал поле nonews если `nonews=0` то выводить все записи, если у юзера `nonews=1` то не выводить его записи. Сделал такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM lenta
WHERE user IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE nonews='0'
               AND id IN (SELECT user FROM frends WHERE frend = '$myid'))
```

Вроде работает, но теперь каждая запись почему то дублируется (выводиться в ленте по две одинаковой записи от пользователя)

Comment: К дублированию такая запись не может приводить в принципе. Вообще прочитайте про join, запросы с ним часто эффективнее, чем с IN

Comment: `select l.* from lenta l inner join user u on u.id = l.user_id where u ....`. Вот эта ваша конструкция вообще взрыв мозга `(SELECT id FROM users WHERE nonews='0' AND id IN (SELECT user FROM frends WHERE frend = '$myid'))` зачем? почему нельзя объединить два условия в одном селекте?

Comment: потому что плохо знаю mysql и не могу из SELECT * FROM lenta WHERE 
user IN (SELECT user FROM frends WHERE frend = '$myid') сделать, то что мне нужно

Comment: Вы просто подумайте или распишите то, что вы выбрали этим селектом. Вы сначала  выполнили выборку "друзей" а потом делаете еще раз выборку где `nonews='0' and id in (друзья)`. а ведь можно сделать выборку где `nonews='0' and юзер = друг`

Comment: сложно мне работать с mysql не могу сформировать готовый запрос

Comment: Несколько раз перечитал вопрос. Пока не понятно чего вы хотите, чтобы записи определенного пользователя не попадали в ленту у него самого или у всех? Зачем вам использовать таблицу `friends`?

Comment: К примеру у меня в списке моих друзей какой то пользователь не хочет что бы его записи отображались в ленте, он включает у себя эту кнопку в настройках приватности, и я вижу все записи моих друзей в ленте кроме того пользователя, который предпочёл что бы его записи не отображались в ленте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже говорили в комментариях оптимальней использовать `JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM lenta AS l
INNER JOIN friends AS f ON l.user = f.user
INNER JOIN users AS u ON l.user = u.id
WHERE f.frend = '$myid' AND nonews='0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Мой вам совет, не углубляйтесь в JOIN'ы. Лента новостей это достаточно быстрорастущая штука (особенно на популярном проекте), этому коду придет конец как только возникнет потребность уменьшить связанность данных. Предлагаю сделать так:

1. Все записи в момент создания помечаются соответствующим флагом nonews (в зависимости от того, хочет пользователь их отображать в общей ленте или не хочет). Этот флаг можно менять при изменении настроек приватности пользователя.
2. При выводе ленты с записями друзей делаем первый запрос, где получаем id всех своих друзей, а во втором запросе указываем эти id в условии WHERE:

   ```
   SELECT user FROM friends WHERE friend = '$myid';
   SELECT * FROM lenta WHERE (friend = '$id_1' OR friend = '$id_2' ...) AND nonews<>1;
   ```
3. Также не забываем выставить индекс на поле friend (в первой таблице) и составной индекс на поля friend, nonews (во второй таблице).

P.S. И совет, приведите в нормальный порядок namespace проекта, посмотрите API любого серьезной платформы (VK, Facebook) и делайте как у них.